# Metapost: variable name with number at the end

Tags: draw, metapost, syntax, variable, declare

Why can't I use variable names like `a1`, `str2`, `x12`? Does Metapost consider them as arrays so that `a1` is like `a[1]` and so on? Even z-notation as `z1`, `z2` and etc. does not work.

The code is

```
beginfig(1);
# := 5mm;
pair z1, z2, z3, z4;
z1 = (10#, #);
z2 = (#, 12#);
z3 = origin;
z4 = (11#, 13#);
draw z1--z2;
draw z3--z4;
endfig;
end;
bye.
```

The error is as follows:

```
! Illegal suffix of declared variable will be flushed.
<to be read again>
                   1
l.153 pair z1
             , z2, z3, z4;
?
```

Comment: @campa Well, I've commented the declaration and there is no any errors with compilation. I thought only numeric variables did not need to be explicitly declared...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of points here.

First you can't put a suffix in a variable declaration.  Instead you have to declare them collectively.  So this works:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
# := 5mm;
pair p[];
p1 = (10#, #);
p2 = (#, 12#);
p3 = origin;
p4 = (11#, 13#);
draw p1--p2;
draw p3--p4;
endfig;
end
```

Secondly, you can't use the variable declaration `z[]` with plain MP because of a special case.   If you try this:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
# := 5mm;
pair z[];
z1 = (10#, #);
z2 = (#, 12#);
z3 = origin;
z4 = (11#, 13#);
draw z1--z2;
draw z3--z4;
endfig;
end
```

you will get this error

```
! Declared variable conflicts with previous vardef.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.5 pair z[];
```

because `plain.mp` has a clever macro defined called `z` that allows you to use `z1`, `z2`, `z3`, etc as pairs *without* any explicit declaration.  So, as the OP discovered, this also works:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
# := 5mm;
z1 = (10#, #);
z2 = (#, 12#);
z3 = origin;
z4 = (11#, 13#);
draw z1--z2;
draw z3--z4;
endfig;
end
```

The clever `vardef` in `plain.mp` is this:

```
vardef z@#=(x@#,y@#) enddef;
```

With this definition, `z1` automatically expands to the literal tokens `(x1, y1)`, where `x1` and `y1` are ordinary `numeric` variables.

This works because MP lets you equate `numeric` variables written as literal pairs like this

```
(a, b) = (3, 4)
```

And as you have discovered, you do not have to declare `numeric` variables.